# MySQL's lower_case_table_names won't change

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive

I have a problem with changing lower_case_table_names variable value in MySQL 5.6 ...
I did all that says in [Where to change the value of lower_case_table_names=2 on windows xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550789/where-to-change-the-value-of-lower-case-table-names-2-on-windows-xampp/17858851#17858851).

The default value on my Windows 7 is '1'. I want to switch it to '2'.

Tried several ways, what I did is:

1. Edited C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my-default.ini by adding  *lower_case_table_names = 2* to wherever I could (without # symbol ofc)
2. Copied my-default.ini and pasted to the same directory, but renamed to my.ini
3. Copied my.ini to \bin folder
4. Restarted MySQL56 service couple times

Now, when I read "SELECT @@lower_case_table_names" it still says 1, and my db behaves like it is 1...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I solved this with a file I found under

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

So, it was **ProgramData**, not Program Files. I got this path from MySQL Workbench -> Manage Server Instances -> [tab] System Profile -> Configuration File. Guess this is the place where one should look for the current config filepath.

Comment: You may need to enable show operating system files to see the **ProgramData** folder. `Start > Run > "RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,Options_RunDLL 0"  > View >` _Uncheck_ **Hide protected operating system files** Also you will need to restart the MySQL Service instance from Windows services.

Comment: Why do they DO this?? Wouldn't it be better for everyone if they put my.ini in the MySQL install folder?? I spent half hour finding this bloody file.