# SELECT @@lower_case_table_names always 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

The answer from *[MySQL's lower_case_table_names won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896829/mysqls-lower-case-table-names-wont-change)* is useless for me since I don't have those additional tools mentioned (MySQL WorkBench and standalone MySQL Server) installed. It used to work fine when I had xampp-win32-5.6.14-0-VC11-installer.exe installed as is over Windows 7 x64. Then everything changed when I replaced [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) 4.4.14 with 4.5.1 due to messy error prompts. No changes to files, restarting or rebooting works.

Should I install those additional tools and apply that change?

Comment: The client side is irrelevant because this parameter is set on the mysql server side. Even if you install mysql as part of xampp, you will have a standalone mysql server. Find the right ini or cnf file, edit the config and restart the mysql server.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You want to make lower_case_table_names = 2 ?

Comment: Yes, but, You know what?

Damn: I thought I reached the limit of options avaliable, but after I decided also to update P.H.P. to the most recent, stable version, I did a clean reinstall and configured the most before starting services. Lower case is finally = 2. I think whole X.A.M.P.P. is fine for now...Patched and now with less reasons to get all-in-one stuff, but fine for now. The question now is:

Should I delete this question or publish this answer. So may someone find this thread useful?

Comment: It's really a judgement call, but I think that as it's written now it's unlikely to be helpful to someone in the future so I am inclined to delete. It seems to be a specific combination of software versions that caused the problem, and when you upgraded to the most recent PHP version the problem was resolved. At worst this _might_ be a XAMPP issue. At the same time, there's nothing wrong with providing an answer with the details of how you fixed it, marking that as accepted, and then letting the community decide -- if someone feels it's not worth keeping around they'll flag it for deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I reached the limit of options available, but after I decided to also update PHP to the most recent, stable version (5.6.15), I did a clean reinstall and configured the most options before starting services. Lower case is finally = 2. I think whole the XAMPP is fine for now... It is patched and now with fewer reasons to get all-in-one stuff, but fine for now.