# change lower_case_table_names MySqlWorkbench

Tags: mysql

Everytime i try to create a new table from a schema with a capital first letter i have i have the message *the server is configured with lower_case_table_names=1 ...*, i checked for solutions and i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896829/mysqls-lower-case-table-names-wont-change), i found the *my.ini* file in ProgramData also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550789/where-to-change-the-value-of-lower-case-table-names-2-on-windows-xampp/17858851#17858851), i added the value `lower_case_table_names = 2` at the end of the file since there was no `# The MySQL server [mysqld]` at least in that file. But nothing happened, i still have the same message. I need the tables upper cased because i have to run scripts to populate them. I also noticed the threads were a couple of years old maybe there's an option to set inside the program ?

Comment: Did you restart mysqld after editing the config file?

Comment: I restarted mysql and now everytime i try to create a new table i have this error "Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `toys`.`test` (
);

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `toys`.`test` (
)
"

Comment: Sounds like your configuration change took hold after restarting the server. Suggest you open up a new question about CREATE TABLE including the full create command that you issued (column names, data types, etc).

Comment: I don't believe they couldn't simply add a simple option to do this ...