# MySql - unable to create new tables after changing my.ini (windows)

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, ddl, create-table

In order to be able to create tables with capital letters I had to modify the `my.ini` file in `ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7`, U added `lower_case_table_names = 2` at the end of the file like it was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896829/mysqls-lower-case-table-names-wont-change), when I closed MySQL server and restarted it couldn't create any new tables, so I removed the line I added, restarted the server again, I keep having this error

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
CREATE TABLE `toys`.`new_table` (
);

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `toys`.`new_table` (
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a table without columns - you need something between the brackets there. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE `toys`.`new_table` (
    id INT -- just for example
);
```