# lower_case_table_name Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, windows-server

I'm trying to set the `lower_case_table_name` value to `2`, since it is a Windows server.  But when I start MySQL Workbench and connect to my server I get the following error:

> A server is in a system that does not properly support the selected `lower_case_table_names` option value.

Shouldn't a Windows server support a value of `2`?  I'm running MySQL 5.6 on Windows Server 2012 and using MySQL Workbench 6.3.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550789/where-to-change-the-value-of-lower-case-table-names-2-on-windows-xampp

Comment: I think this is related to the fact that on Windows, file names are case insensitive. Nevertheless, you can still set this option in my.ini.

Comment: The value is already set to 2, according to the Server Variables in the Workbench. I have already restarted the service. So the comment about possible duplcate is not valid. I did everything that other answers said and it did not solve my issue. mySQL Workbench says the value is set. but I still get the error.

Comment: This bug is still present in latest version of MySQL Workbench (v 8.0.15). I'm writing this in 2019, 4 years after this was reported here for the 1st time.

Answer (score 8):

You can safely ignore this error.

I recently installed MySQL on a new Windows computer and got this error as well after setting `lower_case_table_names` to `2`. I don't remember seeing it previously. However, despite the error it seems to be working properly..tables are created with the proper case and I can do case-insensitive lookups.

Comment: I can confirm Samuel's statement.  I got this message too, but all seemed to work properly

Comment: I got the same error...ignored it...case sensitivity honored and all is good.

Comment: Yes, it's just a warning message of mysql workbench. It works, But pay attention when writing TableName. When you test on windows with lower case tablename. it may raise error on linux.

Comment: A few years later (2022 now) but I'm trying to do exactly this, starting MySQLWorkbench and trying to connect to the db, which has the value set to 2. In my case it's a MariaDB and after clicking on the error-dialogue the Workbench is gone, crashed.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the value to lower_case_table_names = 1 prevents the warning. The windows default is 1. For the setting of this variable see:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: But then all tablenames must be lowercase.

Comment: This is not the correct answer

Comment: There's a reason to set that value to 2 which seems to be the only way on Windows to have names also containing upper-case-letters. Setting it back to 1 would be a step back then.