# Keycloak in Spring Boot cannot apply Liquibase patches

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, keycloak, liquibase

I'm trying to start up a Spring Boot server containing an embedded Keycloak authorization server, [following this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app). Tutorial's code is [here](https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth/tree/0d1839e4b92b84e746ecb7b54339100df895295b/oauth-resource-server/authorization-server). My own adaptation is a MySQL DB, instead of H2, fired up via `docker-compose`

On server start-up, I get this error while DB patches are being applied:
`Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'auth.client_session' doesn't exist`. SequelPro threw same error, but the table is visually there. I solved this by [looking around this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728211/1774643). (a restart was sufficient for me)

Next error was from the next patch, quoting: `keycloak java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'client_attributes' already exists`, and with this one I'm stuck in DB migration limbo, because if I deleted it, it's going to circle back to a "does not exist" error.

Versions:

- *Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE*
- *MySQL 5.7.32*
- *org.keycloak:keycloak-dependencies-server-all:10.0.1*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing MySQL's `lower_case_table_names` config to `1` solves this issue. Inspired by [this answer](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-cache/issues/1#issuecomment-227660557).

To burn this setting via `docker-compose`, customise your command in the `yaml` file (inspired by [this repo](https://github.com/danielpetisme/jhipster-keycloak-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/docker/mysql.yml)):

```
db-service:
  [...]
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1
```

Also make sure the table's encoding is `UTF-8`, to avoid another head scratching error: `keycloak Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535`

Other references:

- [Where to change the value of lower_case_table_names=2 on windows xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550789/1774643)
- [KEYCLOAK-7505 Table 'client_attributes' already exists](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-7505?workflowName=GIT%20Pull%20Request%20workflow%20&stepId=1)
- [Ignore case sensitive for table name in JPA with Hibernate implementation](https://huongdanjava.com/ignore-case-sensitive-for-table-name-in-jpa-with-hibernate-implementation.html)